# The image from quick create in hyper-v for Ubuntu 18.04.2 and 19.04 doesn't allow me to install anything

Tags: gnome, snap, hyper-v, gnome-calculator

I've created a new VM from using the Quick Create function in Hyper-V on windows 10.

Once the VM is setup (I've picked language settings, created a password etc) I then tried to install Visual Studio Code and got the following error message:
`Unable to install "Visual Studio Code": too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged`.

From investigation this appears to be a snap problem.

## Here's some details

`snap --version`:

```
snap    2.38
snapd   2.38
series  16
ubuntu  18.04
kernel  4.15.0-50-generic
```

`snap changes`:

```
ID   Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
1    Doing   today at 10:58 BST  -                   Initialize system state
2    Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Initialize device
```

`snap tasks --last=seed`:

```
Status  Spawn               Ready               Summary
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Ensure prerequisites for "core" are available
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/core_6673.snap" (6673)
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Mount snap "core" (6673)
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Copy snap "core" data
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Setup snap "core" (6673) security profiles
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:58 BST  Make snap "core" (6673) available to the system
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "core"
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Set automatic aliases for snap "core"
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Setup snap "core" aliases
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Run install hook of "core" snap if present
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Start snap "core" (6673) services
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Run configure hook of "core" snap if present
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-3-26-1604" are available
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-3-26-1604_82.snap" (82)
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Mount snap "gnome-3-26-1604" (82)
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Copy snap "gnome-3-26-1604" data
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Setup snap "gnome-3-26-1604" (82) security profiles
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Make snap "gnome-3-26-1604" (82) available to the system
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-3-26-1604"
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-3-26-1604"
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Setup snap "gnome-3-26-1604" aliases
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Run install hook of "gnome-3-26-1604" snap if present
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Start snap "gnome-3-26-1604" (82) services
Done    today at 10:58 BST  today at 10:59 BST  Run configure hook of "gnome-3-26-1604" snap if present
Doing   today at 10:58 BST  -                   Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-calculator" are available
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-calculator_352.snap" (352)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mount snap "gnome-calculator" (352)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Copy snap "gnome-calculator" data
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-calculator" (352) security profiles
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Make snap "gnome-calculator" (352) available to the system
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-calculator"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-calculator"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-calculator" aliases
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run install hook of "gnome-calculator" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Start snap "gnome-calculator" (352) services
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run configure hook of "gnome-calculator" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-characters" are available
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-characters_206.snap" (206)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mount snap "gnome-characters" (206)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Copy snap "gnome-characters" data
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-characters" (206) security profiles
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Make snap "gnome-characters" (206) available to the system
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-characters"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-characters"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-characters" aliases
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run install hook of "gnome-characters" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Start snap "gnome-characters" (206) services
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run configure hook of "gnome-characters" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-logs" are available
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-logs_57.snap" (57)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mount snap "gnome-logs" (57)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Copy snap "gnome-logs" data
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-logs" (57) security profiles
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Make snap "gnome-logs" (57) available to the system
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-logs"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-logs"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-logs" aliases
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run install hook of "gnome-logs" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Start snap "gnome-logs" (57) services
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run configure hook of "gnome-logs" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Ensure prerequisites for "gnome-system-monitor" are available
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gnome-system-monitor_70.snap" (70)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mount snap "gnome-system-monitor" (70)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Copy snap "gnome-system-monitor" data
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-system-monitor" (70) security profiles
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Make snap "gnome-system-monitor" (70) available to the system
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gnome-system-monitor"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Set automatic aliases for snap "gnome-system-monitor"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gnome-system-monitor" aliases
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run install hook of "gnome-system-monitor" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Start snap "gnome-system-monitor" (70) services
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run configure hook of "gnome-system-monitor" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Ensure prerequisites for "gtk-common-themes" are available
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Prepare snap "/var/lib/snapd/seed/snaps/gtk-common-themes_1198.snap" (1198)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mount snap "gtk-common-themes" (1198)
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Copy snap "gtk-common-themes" data
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gtk-common-themes" (1198) security profiles
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Make snap "gtk-common-themes" (1198) available to the system
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "gtk-common-themes"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Set automatic aliases for snap "gtk-common-themes"
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Setup snap "gtk-common-themes" aliases
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run install hook of "gtk-common-themes" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Start snap "gtk-common-themes" (1198) services
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Run configure hook of "gtk-common-themes" snap if present
Do      today at 10:58 BST  -                   Mark system seeded

......................................................................
Make snap "core" (6673) available to the system

2019-05-17T10:58:58+01:00 INFO Requested daemon restart.

......................................................................
Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "core"

2019-05-17T10:58:58+01:00 INFO Waiting for restart...
```

`sudo systemctl status snapd.autoimport`:

```
● snapd.autoimport.service - Auto import assertions from block devices
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.autoimport.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Fri 2019-05-17 16:31:20 BST; 33min ago
           └─ ConditionKernelCommandLine=snap_core was not met
```

Windows details:
- Windows 10, version 1809, (OS Build 17763.437)

## Things I've tried

### 1 - messing around with `/var/lib/snapd/state.json`

I tried the suggestion here: https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/cant-install-or-refresh-snaps-on-arch-linux/8690/28

Which looks like this:

```
sudo systemctl stop snapd
sudo cat /var/lib/snapd/state.json | \
    jq 'delpaths([["data", "auth", "device"]])' > state.json-new
sudo cp state.json-new /var/lib/snapd/state.json
sudo systemctl start snapd
```

However (and this is probably me being a Ubuntu noob) I can't get `jq` to install and I'm not sure exactly what it's doing so I can't do it manually.

### 2 - Using the Ubuntu 19 image

This apparently has the same issue.

### 3 - A colleague tried on his laptop

He had the same issue

### 4 - Reinstall `snapd`

I ran this: `sudo apt install --reinstall snapd` only for the install to get stuck at 67%.

### 5 - messing around with `/var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml`

As per this bug: https://www.mail-archive.com/ubuntu-bugs@lists.ubuntu.com/msg5400922.html

I tried re-ordering the gtk-common-themes part and also removing the gnome-calculator part (rebooting after each change), this appeared to make no difference. The `snap tasks --last=seed` command still showed it getting stuck on the gnome-calculator task.

### 6 - headbutting the keyboard

I felt better but the issue persisted.

### 7 - using a non-quick start image

I downloaded a Ubuntu 18.04.2 ISO and used that. THIS WORKED (as in I could install Visual Studio Code and the snap commands looked healthy). However, it doesn't have all the nice hyper-v stuff so the screen res sucked, no copy and paste, mouse was very laggy etc...

I could install the various bits to make this image more hyper-v friendly but I have a feeling I'll never get as slick as the official one. If I can fix the `snap` on this one I think I'll end up with the best UX.

### 8 - THIS WORKS. messing around with `/var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml` part 2

I removed a bunch of stuff from my `/var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml` so it now looks like this:

```
snaps:
  -
    name: core
    channel: stable
    file: core_6673.snap
  -
    name: gtk-common-themes
    channel: stable/ubuntu-18.04
    file: gtk-common-themes_1198.snap
  -
    name: gnome-3-26-1604
    channel: stable/ubuntu-18.04
    file: gnome-3-26-1604_82.snap
```

And then did `snap abort --last=seed` followed by `sudo systemctl restart snapd`. Check `snap tasks --last=seed` - they should all be complete and you can do install snaps (such as Visual Studio Code).

Someone smarter than me will probably point out the horrible side affects this will cause.

Comment: I can confirm that this helped, however what it does is it removes the packages not only from yaml, but also from system (they are not visible anymore)... What I did is simply reinstalled them back (some of them, the rest got reinstalled automatically)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently the seed.yml file specifies apps to install on a fresh OS install.

If we remove the ones that are getting stuck and then manually install them, this works.

Steps:

1. Change your `/var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml` file to look like this:

   ```
   snaps:
   -
   name: core
   channel: stable
   file: core_6673.snap
   -
   name: gtk-common-themes
   channel: stable/ubuntu-18.04
   file: gtk-common-themes_1198.snap
   -
   name: gnome-3-26-1604
   channel: stable/ubuntu-18.04
   file: gnome-3-26-1604_82.snap
   ```

   Basically I'm removing all the entries that caused the snap tasks to get stuck.
2. Abort the currently running snap tasks and restart the service:

   - `snap abort --last=seed`
   - `sudo systemctl restart snapd`
   - Keep running `snap tasks --last=seed` to see the progress of the snap tasks and wait for all the tasks to be "Done"
3. Manually install any apps that you removed from `/var/lib/snapd/seed/seed.yaml`, they might include:

   - `gnome-calculator`
   - `gnome-characters`
   - `gnome-logs`
   - `gnome-system-monitor`

   The command to reinstall these is:

   ```
   snap install gnome-calculator gnome-characters gnome-logs gnome-system-monitor`
   ```

#### Credit

Thanks to [Stefan Jarina](https://askubuntu.com/users/955193/stefan-jarina) for help resolving this issue!

Comment: Same issue remains on Hyper V Ubuntu 19.04 image. Problem solved with your solution above! It took be a while to find your post though as I was searching / googling with 19.04. Maybe you can add this version in question title for better index search.

Comment: Thanks! Great suggestion. Done!