# Cant' install in Ubuntu core using snap

Tags: snap, ubuntu-core

I get this message trying to install anything using `snap`:

```
~$ sudo snap install hello-world
   error: too early for operation, device not yet seeded or device model not acknowledged
```

Can anyone please explain this error and the way to solve it?

Comment: Did you try to look for the solution even once? I'm going to mark it as a duplicate. In the future when you come across some error then please try to search for it and do some research before posting it in here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Snaps won't install in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1107388/snaps-wont-install-in-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Why do you assume I have not done that?
BTW its Ubuntu Core not regular Ubuntu, that is why I open a new topic.

Comment: For obvious reason that I marked it as duplicate. Please refer to the link I provided. Moreover you posted the question without mentioning any solution that you tried. So any prudent person would assume that you didn't do any research